# Program not starting because of missing runtimes which are actually there

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, vcredist

I have a MFC project created in VS2008. I've recently upgraded the solution to VS2013.

When I install the application on another computer, I get an error stating that msvcp120.dll is missing.
The problem is that the file actually does exist in the Microsoft.VC120.CRT folder (which is in the same folder as the executable). 
However, if I move that file outside the Microsoft.VC120.CRT folder (and in the same as the executable), it works.

What do I have to do for the executable to work while the dll is in the Microsoft.VC120.CRT folder? Do I have to change a setting in VS2013 or something?

Comment: The system uses a documented [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) to resolve dependencies. Subdirectories to the executable image are not part of the search order.

Comment: The how come it used to work before? I just had the dll in the Microsoft.VC90.CRT folder. It was the same thing and it worked.

Comment: No, it wasn't working like you think it was. On your dev machine, you had Visual Studio installed, which just happened to install the CRT binaries in a location, that was part of the Dynamic-Link Library Search Order. Run your application under a debugger, like Visual Studio, and switch to the *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Modules*. It'll show you, **where** the modules are loaded from. It's not the location you think it is.